# Multiple columns with same GUID, getting most recent column per GUID

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with a few million columns. There are two or three columns with the same GUID; each one contains slightly different information due to modification - History is stored for other purposes. I want to get exactly one column per GUID, the newest one based on a unix timestamp column, stored as a unix timestamp.

For example:

```
id    guid    body         timestamp
1     dhf     Hello world  3857370
2     jdr     Hello        3852062
3     leb     Goodbye      3105893
4     dhf     Hello earth  3857362
5     leb     Bye          3105891
6     jdr     Hi           3852068
7     dhf     Test msg     3857374
```

Should return:

```
id    guid    body         timestamp
5     leb     Bye          3105891
6     jdr     Hi           3852068
3     leb     Goodbye      3105893
```

Output order doesn't matter. I'm not sure where to start with this at all.

Comment: By columns you actually mean rows, right? What about dhf guid?

Comment: @KamilG. Sorry about that, my example is rubbish. Yes, I mean rows.

Comment: Don't you mean "row" in place of "column"?  If so, please edit the question.  In your example there is only one "column" with guids in it; multiple "rows" have the same "dhf" guid.

Comment: After you have dedupped the guid column, get rid of `id` and change to `PRIMARY KEY(guid)`.  That way, you won't get dups ever again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.guid = t.guid
                    );
```

For performance, create an index on `t(guid, timestamp)`.

Comment: I'm trying to add on an AND statement after your check, but it causes it to return 0 rows. The exact code I'm adding after yours is:

AND convo_id IN (SELECT convo_id FROM Conversations WHERE perspective_user=? AND identity=? AND timestamp_added=?); (The ? are replaced with actual data and work fine in another query)

Comment: @Stephen . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Using GROUP BY and JOIN:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TEST_TABLE t
  INNER JOIN (SELECT GUID, MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS MAX_TIMESTAMP
                FROM TEST_TABLE 
                GROUP BY GUID) t2
    ON t2.GUID = t.GUID AND
       t2.MAX_TIMESTAMP = t.TIMESTAMP
  ORDER BY t.GUID
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Be sure to include `INDEX(guid, timestamp)` (in either order).